# Swagger: swagger.json interface

Tags: php, swagger

i tried to work with marketplace. They said that "Working with the API consists of sending a request and receiving a response. To do this, you can use the console to the right of the method descriptions, the Swagger interface"

Also, the link of "Swagger interface" => https://api-seller.ozon.ru/docs/#/
looks like this:
[image]

I`m a little bit confused, because i expected, that this is the library, or smth like this.

Link swagger.json [image]

it`s a page with to json setting(as i think), picture is pretty view of plain text on that page:
[image]

so, i have no swagger library, but have this json.

#### Question:

Can i make from this json Swagger project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on swagger.json (as you shown in image with red arrow) it will redirect you to another page, this page have json configuration.
Copy this json and open https://editor.swagger.io/ this link, and paste your json.
After that, there is an option on menu 'Generate Client' it give you a various options to generate your client in Angular, C# and so on

Comment: wow, this is absolutely it. Thank you so much)